# What is the difference between clipnorm and clipval on Keras

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, deep-learning, gradient-descent

What is the difference between clipnorm and clipval.

Ex: `opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=1.0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incase of `clipnorm`, the l2 norm of the gradients is capped at the specified value.

While `clipvalue` caps the gradient values such that they don't exceed the specified value